# Matlab 3D scatter plot - extract section of data

Tags: matlab, extract

I have data file which consists of x, y, z values. What should I do to extract a data sets for a given x or y or z value.
For e.g Consider the following data

```
x   y   z
1   5   5
2   5   4
2   7   5
2   8   9
2   -5  -9
3   6   9   
2   5   7   
8   7   5
9   6   4
-8  9   6
1   6   4
```

Now I want to extract data sets which corresponds only to x=2. How can I do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

The more Matlab-style solution to this problem is to use the `find` command and the `save` command:

```
function extract(data,index,value)
    I=find(data(:,index)==value));
    excerpt_data = data(I,:);
    save('extract.txt','excerpt_data','-ascii','-tabs');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for this

```
function extract(data,index,value)
file = fopen('extract.txt','a');
for i = 1:length(data(:,index))
    if data(i,index) == value
        fprintf(file, '%f\t%f\t%f\n', data(i,1),data(i,2),data(i,3));  
    end
end
fclose(file)
```

Here data corresponds to the file containing x,y,z values. Index represents the x , y , z index which take value 1, 2, 3 respectively.(x in  the e.g given in question so index is 1) Value corresponds to the value for which you want to extract.(2 in the e.g given in question)